# How do I restore the effect of the Ctrl + comma key that arranged my tab?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, google-docs, international

I was writing something on google docs when I tried to write a subscript using the ctrl + comma key. I got no subscripts, instead, it broke my Chrome tabs order. My tabs are ordered based on their homepage address (e.g. 4 Amazon homepages are clustered together: first to the fourth tabs are all amazons, then fifth and on are the rest). I am using a Japanese keyboard layout with an English (United States) input method, in case this comma also means something else.

Also, how do you configure Chrome shortcuts/keybindings nowadays? I can not find an easy way to do it.

Comment: 1. Most browsers let you *drag* a tab to a different location. Does Chrome not let you restore the order? 2. There *might* be third-party extensions to redirect keyboard shortcuts: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-turn-off-keyboard-shortcuts-in-Chrome , or just use a different browser.

Comment: It's a well-known problem since long ago that not all Google apps keyboard shortcuts work fine on international keyboards. What do you mean by "restore"? Do you know if this keyboard shortcut has worked before in the current environment? What is the name and version of the operative system that you are using?

Comment: @Wicket I have tried to order my tabs to what I wanted for faster work. A simple mistake of "Win + ," broke that order.  I pressed that key combination because I was expecting a subscript shortcut while working inside the Google Docs. I use Windows 11.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I can drag the tabs, but it is too many and I do not remember every tabs position. Thank you for the link!